# "User" model broken after Laravel 4.1 upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have upgraded Laravel from 4.0 to 4.1 recently in a few instances. Today I did the upgrade in yet another instance and found out that there is something wrong with the User model. The `models/User.php` file is still there, but I don't think it is used by Laravel anymore. My question is: why?

To demonstrate the issue, I have created the following entries in my **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('test1', function()
{
  $course = Course::find(4);
  return ($course->users()->first());
});

Route::get('test2', function()
{
  $user = User::find(22);
  return ($user->courses()->first());
});
```

Both these entries are correct regarding syntax and the database object (course with id 4 exists and user with id 22 exists). My **Course.php** model has the following:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('participant_role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And my **User.php** has a corresponding entry:

```
public function courses()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Course')->withPivot('participant_role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now if I launch the first URL, `/test1`, I get a working JSON entry as a result. As expected.

With the second URL, `/test2` however I get an error message:

```
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::courses()

open: /home/simoa/laravelapps/clientname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php `
```

I think there is something wrong here. Why is my Laravel instance trying to call the `courses()` method from the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class? That isn't normal, right?

As I said earlier, everything else works perfectly, except things to do with the User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by an invalid entry in the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

For some reason during the 4.1 upgrade (probably running the command: `composer update`) the entry for `'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/User.php'` has turned into `'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/old_User.php'` in that file.

I did have an old backup/dev file called `old_User.php`in my models directory and for some reason, it seems, composer has mapped User class to that file.

Solution: delete old_User.php and re-run composer update.

Answer (score 1):

try running `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your suggestion did not help in my case.

Comment: try `return $user->courses()->getResults()->first();`?
`$user->courses()` returns a `BelongsToMany` class

Comment: That still does not help. I think the syntax is correct, because `$course->users()->first();` in fact works while it also uses `belongsToMany` relationship. For some reason the methods within User model are not found...

Comment: Now I figured out that the issue is caused by an entry in the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`. For some reason during the 4.1 upgrade (composer update, I guess) the entry `'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/User.php'` has turned into `'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/old_User.php'`. I have no idea why this happened. I do have that file `old_User.php`in my models directory.